# which loader should I use for BrowserRouter in webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am new to webpack and I am trying to run npm run dev script which is:

long story short the error indicates it doesn't have loader for BrowserRouter files.
how I suppose to add a loader for it?
beneath there is the output I get.

```
> graduates-platform@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\97252\Desktop\work\infinity_graduates\graduates-platform\
> webpack --mode development --watch ./graduates_platform/frontend/src/index.js --output-path ./graduates_platform/frontend/static/frontend/main.js\

[webpack-cli] Compilation starting...\
[webpack-cli] Compilation finished\
asset main.js 14 KiB [emitted] (name: main)\
runtime modules 931 bytes 4 modules\
cacheable modules 7.25 KiB\
  ./graduates_platform/frontend/src/index.js 292 bytes [built] [code generated]\
  ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js 6.67 KiB [built] [code generated]\
  ./graduates_platform/frontend/src/index.js 307 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]\

ERROR in ./graduates_platform/frontend/src/index.js 8:2\
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:2)\
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders\
|
| ReactDOM.render(\
>   <BrowserRouter>\
|     <App />\
|   </BrowserRouter>,\
 @ ./graduates_platform/frontend/src/index.js 2:12-47 9:17-24 13:15-29\
```

webpack 5.6.0 compiled with 1 error in 230 ms

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with BrowserRouter the issue is in webpack setup. The React code you are running is Jsx format which need to be converted. The webpack uses the concept of loaders to achieve thhat. So you might have to setup `babel-loader`.

i.e

```
       ...
       rules:[{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: /\.js$|jsx/,
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
       ...
```